# filter "the max count" for array in laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have an array in Laravel. I want to show some value of this array on the index page.

my array:

```php
$product = [
    '0' => array(
     'name' => 'product1',
     'count' => '30'
),
    '1' => array(
     'name' => 'product2',
     'count' => '2'
),
    '2' => array(
     'name' => 'product3',
     'count' => '5'
),
    '3' => array(
     'name' => 'product4',
     'count' => '33'
),
    '4' => array(
     'name' => 'product5',
     'count' => '30'
),
    '5' => array(
     'name' => 'product6',
     'count' => '29'
)];
```

I want to show from the highest quantity to the lowest value and limit this to 4 counts.

like this

```html
<h2>product4</h2>
<p>33</p>
<hr>

<h2>product1</h2>
<p>30</p>
<hr>

<h2>product5</h2>
<p>30</p>
<hr>

<h2>product6</h2>
<p>29</p>
<hr>
```

Comment: use order desc. and limit 4

Comment: @aryahteran, can you show an attempt you have made to solve this question and what problems you faced in the process?

Comment: The array is the result of a query?

Comment: If you're getting this data from a database you should rather sort and limit the data in a database query instead for better performance. Have a look at Laravel's [Ordering, Grouping, Limit, & Offset documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use **array_multisort**:

```
array_multisort(array_column($product, 'count'), SORT_DESC, $product);
```

Comment: This is a duplicate @DilipHirapara's answer. OP a little bit weird

Comment: I don't understand why OP selected his answer even I made the example for him and he copied my answer..

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
 $sortedarray = collect($product)->sortBy('count')->reverse()->take(4)->toArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

try to use `array_multisort` ([documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php))

```
array_multisort(array_column($product, 'count'), SORT_DESC, $product);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($product);
exit;
```

[Check example](https://paiza.io/projects/udxPNh2yiVg5COZC-Cqi1g)

Answer (score 1):

Sorted array push into `foreach` loop:

```
public function getSortedProducts(){

    $product = [
        '0' => array(
         'name' => 'product1',
         'count' => '30'
    ),
        '1' => array(
         'name' => 'product2',
         'count' => '2'
    ),
        '2' => array(
         'name' => 'product3',
         'count' => '5'
    ),
        '3' => array(
         'name' => 'product4',
         'count' => '33'
    ),
        '4' => array(
         'name' => 'product5',
         'count' => '30'
    ),
        '5' => array(
         'name' => 'product6',
         'count' => '29'
    )]; 

    array_multisort(array_column($product, 'count'), SORT_DESC, $product);

    return view('your_blade_name',compact('product'));
}
```

**Blade:**

```
@foreach($product as $row)
        @if($loop->iteration > 5) // or other logic
            @break
        @endif
    <h3>{{ $row['name'] }}</h3>
    <p>{{ $row['count'] }}</p>
    <hr> 
@endforeach
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer with detailed.

Answer (score 0):

Use **usort** function

```
function sortByCount($a, $b) {
   return $b['count'] - $a['count'];
}
usort($product,'sortByCount');
print_r($product);

foreach($product as $k => $val){
   if($k <= 3){
      echo "Your HTML";
      echo '<br/>';
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
$sorted = collect($product)->sortByDesc('count')->toArray();  // for sort array
$output = array_slice($sorted, 0, 4);  // for return first four indexs
```